# Why am I missing C++20 headers? And how do I fix this?

Tags: c++, g++, clang++, ubuntu-20.04, libc++

I've been Googling around for months trying to solve this, but nothing I've tried works.

So a simple program like this:

```cpp
#include <concepts>
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    std::cout << "Test" << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

fails to compile with the error message `fatal error: 'concepts' file not found`.  This happens with both clang++ and g++ compilers.  (For completeness: `clang++-11 -std=c++20 test.cpp` and `g++ -std=c++2a test.cpp`.)

My compiler versions are:

```
> clang++-11 --version
Ubuntu clang version 11.0.0-2~ubuntu20.04.1

> g++ --version
g++ (Ubuntu 9.3.0-17ubuntu1~20.04) 9.3.0
```

If I look for my C++ headers, I can find them in `/usr/include/c++`:

```
> find /usr -name "iostream"
/usr/lib/llvm-10/include/c++/v1/iostream
/usr/include/c++/9/iostream
```

However, `find /usr -name "concepts"` gives nothing.  So the header is definitely missing.  Along with all the other C++20-specific headers, and C++20-specific functions that are defined in other headers (like `[std::bit_width][1]` for example - the header can be included but the function is not defined).

And by the way, I can use all C++20 *functionality*. For example, I can define my own concepts, although I can't use the concepts header.

What's weird is everywhere I Google for this type of issue, the only problems I can find are people who are using an old compiler that doesn't support C++20, or are missing all C++ headers (or the compiler can't find them). But I'm not sure what I'm supposed to do given that my compiler clearly supports C++20, yet I'm missing the C++20 headers.

I did try to see if `libstdc++` needed an update, but to no avail:

```
> sudo apt install libc++-dev
[...]
libc++-dev is already the newest version (1:10.0-50~exp1).
```

Comment: There's a nice [feature test](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/feature_test) program (in the example area) that you can compile and run using C++20 and the resulting program will tell you which C++20 features are available in your particular compiler.  (Many compilers are not 100% complete in their C++20 implementations yet.)

Comment: gcc supports concepts since version 10.

Answer (score 6):

So I needed `g++` version 10 installed to get the required headers.  I thought I had the latest version of everything, but I think I may have updated `gcc` rather than `g++`.  To anyone having this issue, make sure to double check your `g++ --version`, not `gcc --version` in case they are different.

Anyway, the following solved the issue:

`sudo apt install g++-10`